# HTTP METHOD categorization cancel vs. delete

Tags: python, rest, http

In an API, what `HTTP METHOD` should be used for a cancel operation.

I imagine this wouldn't be a `DELETE` request, because the resource is not being disposed of. In which case, should it be a `POST` or a `PUT` ? Here is some documentation, but I still am not clear on the distinction from this: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html

Comment: RFC 2616 is irrelevant.

You may want to read RFC 7231.

Answer (score 12):

This isn't a DELETE. Cancelling an operation is a state change and a state change means an update.

I would personally use a PUT because you normally know the URI of the resource you are updating.

Also see this post for more details: [PUT vs POST in REST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630453/put-vs-post-in-rest).